# How to calculate run time for fork() system call in C?

Tags: c, time, fork, child-process

I'm trying to find the run time of the `fork()` system call. Each child process needs to immediately exit, and the parent needs to `wait()` on each child before creating the next. I also want to use the shell built-in command named `time` to measure the execution time of a program.

I have this code so far, but not sure If I'm doing it right.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int global = 100;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int local = 5;

    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error -- failed to fork()");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid > 0) {

        int child_ret;

        waitpid(pid, &child_ret, 0);
        printf("parent -- global: %i, local: %i\n", global, local);
        printf("parent -- child exited with code %i\n", child_ret);
    } else {
        global++;
        local++;

        printf("child -- global: %i, local: %i\n", global, local);
        exit (0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `getrusage` system call.

Comment: Does the code work?  If yes, you should post on codereview.stackexchange.com.  If the code does not work, please say exactly why you think so: what error or unexpected behavior are you observing?

Comment: You're problably confused because the `local` and `global` don't change for your parent-process, but yes, your code looks correct.

Comment: You should not call `exit` in the child. You should call `_exit`. If you call `exit` in the child, it will run all the parent's "at exit" handlers, and the results of running an at exit handler twice can be unpredictable. This has caused serious bugs with security consequences in the past, so don't get into the habit of mismanaging processes.

Answer (score 2):

Read first [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and consider using [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2html) & [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html); you could use `clock_gettime` around the `fork` (in the parent process) if you wanted only to measure the time for that [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) syscall itself (it is very small - perhaps a millisecond -, and not really significant).

Use `errno` (e.g. print `strerror(errno)` or use `perror`) in failure cases.

Notice that `fork` timing might slightly depends upon the size of your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) and [resident set size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size). You might also use `strace` timing abilities; in practice `fork` is quick enough (often, less than one millisecond, and sometimes a few dozens of microseconds; because it is using lazy [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) techniques)

So the `fork` is quick, the child `execve`  could take a few more microseconds, the program startup time in the child is also significant ([ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) is performing some [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) before your `main` of the `exec`-ed program starts...). **What *exactly* do you want to measure?**

In general, the child process quickly calls [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) which also takes some time (and of course the executed program may take some arbitrarily long time to finish, and might even "never" finish if it is server like). Perhaps what could matter is the time between just before the `fork`  and the first meaningful instruction in the `main` of the `execve`-d program in the child process...

In fact, you can start many processes; a rule of thumb is to `fork` at most a few hundred times per second, and only if the child is *quickly* `execve`-ing some *quick* program (like `/bin/ls` of a few dozen files, or `date`). However, you don't want to have more than a dozen or two of *runnable* processes at once (on a laptop or desktop), and perhaps even less than 5 runnable processes...